# Coherence: Gracefully navigate a POF Path with potential null elements

Tags: oracle-coherence

In POF-serialized .NET objects, I have Class A containing Class B, and Class B has an Attribute X which I want to extract and use in a filter.

I can use a `SimplePofPath` to navigate through the POF stream from A to B and grab X. This works well, except when `A.B == null`.

When A does not have an instance of B where expected, the `SimplePofPath` fails with message

> getChild() method cannot be invoked on
>   the SimplePofValue instance.

Instead of this, I would like an `IPofNavigator` that does something more graceful than throw an exception when it can't traverse its path because I serialized `null` in a field. This could be, say, returning a user-supplied "fallback" value.

Does such an implementation exist? If not, how would I get started extending `AbstractPofPath` on my own? I have taken a look at [this](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1023196) custom navigator dealing with contained collections, but can't wrap my head around how to get started implementing `navigate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by extending `AbstractPofPath` and implementing a recursive `navigate(PofValue, int)` method much like the one linked. I also stubbed it in C# and provided matching `user-type` configurations in the .NET client and cluster config files.

Before the recursive call, the method checks to see if its parameter has a typeID equal to `PofConstants.V_REFERENCE_NULL`, and if so, it simply returns its parameter instead of recursing.

Past few minutes of testing show that this approach maintains behavior acceptable to `Filter` and `Extractor` objects.

**Further Thoughts:**
If I had Java equivalents of my .NET classes, I could use `ChainedExtractor`s. However, the cluster wants to know how to deserialize everything in the chain of extractors ;)